# Setting up correct REGEX for conversion tracking target-URL in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, conversion-tracking

Greetings from Norway!

I am new with setting up REGEX in Google analytics, so I would really appreciate your help! :)
I want to track sent campaign forms from my website (like recipt urls), but I need to set up a regular expression in order to track the responses for all campaigns on my website.

These strings need to be tracked (and similar onces in the future):

https://www.domain.no/**Campaigns**/MYcampaignname?**mode=received&formid**=thisand093that123
https://www.domain.no/**Campaigns**/Another-campaign-name?**mode=received&formid**=76280&goback=https%3a%2f%2fwww.domain.no%2fCampaign
https://www.domain.no/**Campaigns**/Name-of-This-campaign?**mode=received&formid**=76283

I have tried several different regular expressions in GA, but I do not get them to work..
Some I have tried:

/Campaigns/.*?mode=received&formid=.*

/Campaigns/([A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+)?mode=received&formid=[^/]

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Special chars need to be escaped, particularly `?` should be `\?`

Comment: You probably want `^/Campaigns/[^/]+\?mode=received&formid=[^/]+`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! :) :) :)

Comment: You're welcome, one minor change would be to add a dollar sign to the end like this `^/Campaigns/[^/]+\?mode=received&formid=[^/]+$`

Comment: Thank you! 
Did a few tests now, and the tracking didn't work with the '$' in the end. The actual string on the receipt page looked like this: https://www.domain.no/Campaigns/Hyundai-Santa-Fe?mode=received&formid=76312&goback=https%3a%2f%2fwww.domain.no%2f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
^/Campaigns/([\w-]+)\?mode=received&formid=([^/]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Wz4iH5/1)

**Explanation**

| MODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| ^ | the beginning of the string |
| /Campaigns/ | '/Campaigns/' |
| ( | group and capture to \1: |
| [\w-]+ | any character of: word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| ) | end of \1 |
| ? | '?' |
| mode=received&formid= | 'mode=received&formid=' |
| ( | group and capture to \2: |
| [^/]+ | any character except: '/' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| ) | end of \2 |

Comment: @KingKongFive Please kindly accept/upvote the answer